# Killing a process launched from a process that has ended - Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to kill a process in Python, that is being launched from another process and I am unable to find the correct place to place my ".terminate()".

To explain myself better I will post some example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def function():
    print "Here is where I am creating the function I need to kill"
    ProcessToKill = Process(target = killMe)
    ProcessToKill.start()

def killMe():
    while True:
        print "kill me"
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process1 = Process(target = function)
    Process1.start()
```

My question is, where can I place ProcessToKill.terminate(), ideally without having to change the overall structure of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold onto the `ProcessToKill` object so that you can kill it later:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def function():
    print "Here is where I am creating the function I need to kill"
    ProcessToKill = Process(target = killMe)
    ProcessToKill.start()
    return ProcessToKill

def killMe():
    while True:
        print "kill me"
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process1 = function()
    time.sleep(5)
    Process1.terminate()
```

Here, I've removed your wrapping of `function` in another `Process` object, because for the example it seems redundant, but you should be able to do the same thing with a `Process` that runs another `Process`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will go test it, if successful I will mark this an answered

Comment: I find that I can't actually terminate a `Process` that runs another `Process`, so I suppose my answer means that you might have to change your code structure a bit.  Do you really need a `Process` that runs another `Process`?

Comment: Just tested it, the process that called another process did alot of other stuff as well, but I built a middleman function that would call the second process and it works perfectly, thanks alot!